# mysql LOAD DATA INTOFILE ERROR 1064 42000 error line 1

Tags: mysql

I'm trying this and for some reason is not working.
I'm suspecting it may be the `-` but not totally sure.

I have read the mysql manual but does not say how to scape or what exactly this error is about, I mean it does but is confusing..

```
mysql> LOAD DATA INFILE 'meow-ever.txt' INTO TABLE meow-ever
    -> ;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-ever' at line 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must escape your table name, like that :

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'meow-ever.txt' INTO TABLE `meow-eve`
```

Notice it's not regular quote, I don't remember how you can type it on a qwerty keyboard sorry :)

Comment: Isn't the escaping alright here or is it just a character that looks like backticks (`)?